# Bootstrap modal POST issues with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've been trying to create a confirm delete popup in a modal via bootstrap. I was initially having issues with posting via plain php, but now I don't know whether my AJAX code is working or not. If I create an alert on error and success, both of them alert.
Here is the following code:

Modal:

```
        <div id="delete_data_Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Member</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="post" id="deleteMember">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $deleteMemberID ?>">
                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this member?</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger"
                                    id="deleteConfirm">Delete
                            </button>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PHP code when confirm delete is clicked:

```
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['deleteConfirm'])) {
            $deleteMemberID = $_POST['MemberID'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_Members WHERE tbl_Members.MemberID = %{$deleteMemberID}";
            $update = mysqli_query($DB, $sql);
            echo "<script>alert('DELETED')</script>";
        }
        ?>
```

and finally, my AJAX code.

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#deleteMember').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: alert("yay"),
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I'm relatively new to PHP, and extremely new to AJAX (Have never used it before this), so I don't know how obvious the issue could be. Any comments would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: what errors you get?

Comment: @daremachine the SQL code does not execute. it shouldn't be a javascript related issue, because monitoring the console on firefox doesn't spit out any errors, and the php logs for the webpage does not output any errors.

Comment: Also success should be success: function(data) { alert('yay'); }

Comment: You probably missing `deleteConfirm` in your data. Try check if exist on post.

Comment: @daremachine I have now wrapped success. where abouts in my data would I be missing deleteConfirm? Thanks for your response.

Comment: In php script. PHP is ok except % in query. Remove it.

Comment: what is `value="<?php echo $deleteMemberID ?>"`?? also name attribute is missing  and you wont get any of the form data without name while `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: @NijinKoderi the ```value="<?php echo $deleteMemberID ?>"``` is because it's being designed to be a feature where you search for members, and you have the options of either deleting or editing the details of each member.